# How to get the order of a pandas series with dates?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series containing 50 dates and I want to return a series containing the order of the dates.
The date series looks like this:

```
0     1900-01-20
1     1970-02-25
2     1885-04-10

...
```

The output series should look like this:

```
0     2
1     3
2     1
...
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) function:

```
s.rank()
```